# Django: Create Serializer validation fields not used

Tags: django, angular, serialization

Just a quick question about the `Serializers` in Django RestFramework.
Especially about the `create` class.

I thought that the `CreateSerializer` was about what was needed for the Object creation.
For exemple my `UserCreateSerializer`:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from ..models.model_user import *

class UserCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'id',
            'username',
            'password',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'is_a',
            'is_e',
            'is_b',
            'profile'
        ]
        extra_kwargs = {
        'password': {'write_only': True},
        'id': {'read_only': True},
        'profile': {'read_only': True}
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            password=validated_data['password'],
            first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
            last_name=validated_data['last_name'],
            email=validated_data['email'],
            is_a=validated_data['is_a'],
            is_e=validated_data['is_e'],
            is_b=validated_data['is_b']
            )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

And so when in my Angular FrontEnd I `POST` a new user like so:

```ts
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: [''],
      password: [''],
      first_name: [''],
      last_name: [''],
      email: [''],
      is_a: [null],
      is_e: [null],
      is_b: [null]
    });
  }

  createUserOnSubmit() {
    this.http.post(this.ROOT_URL + 'users/',
    this.registerForm.value).subscribe(
            response => {
              console.log("yolo", response);
              console.log(response['id']);
              this.redirectUser(response['id']);
            },
            error => {
              console.log("yolo-error", error);
            });
  }

  redirectUser(userId: number) {
    this.router.navigate(['user/', userId]);
  }

}
```

I `POST` the new user without any `id` and `profile` (the profile being created upon user creation with an event listener in the BackEnd), it doesn't bother the BackEnd and the fact that I'm including the `profile` in my `UserCreateSerializer` sends me back in the console the new user values including the `user.profile.id`

What is the point of the "fields" from the UserCreateSerializer, to make sure that all the indicated fields are provided in the POST request (doesn't seem to be the case), or to return an object with those specific fields with a 201 code?

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Fields in Meta class only tells the corresponding models fields to be serialized/deserialized for different http methods.

Comment: So does it mean that when it receives the http request it deserializes those fields and making them required?
Or does it mean it serializes those fields in its response?